# How To Print Strings Between Integer Ranges - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I'm very new to Python and programming in general, so excuse me if the code is terrible and the problem rather easy to solve.

I have written code to allow a user to have employee data printed based on 3 different inputs, which they are allowed to choose from.
The options the user has available to them are to pick employees based on their payroll number; a minimum and maximum salary range; their job title.

I made two functions for the formatting. The first one turns the lines of the text file into lists, then the second function grabs those individual lists and formats them.

Then the code requests the user to input the file name. If the file cannot be found, they get to try again. If it is correct, the file is loaded and then runs through the functions to print out a neat table.

Then the user is asked what method they want to choose from to select specific employees. They are given 4 options, 3 are mentioned at the start and the fourth is to just end the program.

I managed to successfully get the first option to print out the employees without hassle, as is the same for the fourth option to end the program. I almost have the third one completed, I just need to find a way to print the name without a comma. **My problem resides within the second option: how do I print the employees and their details if they fall between the minimum and maximum salary ranges entered by the user if the range isn't an integer since it has to include a '£' sign?**

Here's the code. It's the biggest chunk in the program because I just have no clue how to make it work properly -

```
def detailsPrint(field) :   #takes tuple and prints
print("{:30}" "{:6}" "{:15}" "{:7}".format(field[3] + ", " + field[4], field[0], field[2], "£" + field[1]))

if display == 2 :
        maxSalary = "£1000000"
        minpay = input("Enter the minimum pay : ")
        maxpay = input("Enter the maximum pay : ")
        if len(minpay) and len(maxpay) < maxSalary :
            for s in employeeList :
                if s[1] >= minpay :
                    detailsPrint(s)
```

The outcome should be something like (example) `Simpson, Bart   12345 Consultant   £55000` if the minpay were to be £50000 and maxpay £60000

**edit: Managed to get it working. Here's the code**

```
if display == 2 :
        x = False
        maxSalary = 1000000
        minpay = int(input("Enter the minimum pay: "))
        maxpay = int(input("Enter the maximum pay: "))
        if int(minpay) > int(maxSalary) or int(maxpay) > int(maxSalary) :
            x = False
            print("No employees earn over £1000000. Try again.")
        if int(minpay) or int(maxpay) < int(maxSalary) :
            for s in employeeList :
                if int(s[1]) >= minpay and int(s[1]) <= maxpay :
                    detailsPrint(s)
                    x = True
        if x == False :
            print("No employees could be found within that range. Try again")
            print("\n")
```

Comment: Your question should include a mcve. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, note that `salary` can be an `int`. Just convert it to `str` and add the relevant symbol when you want to print it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that `if len(minpay) or len(maxpay) > maxSalary:` will resolve as you're expecting.  You must check each value separately like `if valueOne > maxLimit or valueTwo > maxLimit:`

Comment: I tried to make the code snippet a bit more compact and easier to read. Sorry for copying the entire thing last time

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution: don't ask for the £ char ;-)

A solution that work with your requirement is to change the line

`if len(minpay) or len(maxpay) > maxSalary :`

with something like

`if int(minpay[1:]) > int(maxSalary[1:]) or int(maxpay[1:]) > int(maxSalary[1:]) :`

which check the numeric value of the strings (your condition seems wrong anyway to me)

Comment: That bit is just to prevent incorrect answers from being entered so I'm not too worried about that. The more concerning section is just after it, which is supposed to find and print the correct employees

Comment: That bit probably prevents the execution of the following for loop, if it does not give you an error: len(minpay) and len(maxpay) return a Integer and you are cheking against a string. The Python intepreter on my machine is not happy about this condition (TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all "£" signs to "" in a string.

```
YourString.replace("£", "")
```